What is the purpose of Back and Forward ribbon/quick access toolbar commands in PowerPoint?
How to access them: either customize quick access toolbar or the ribbon → Choose commands from: All Commands (or Commands Not in the Ribbon) → Back, Forward (WebGoForward)
I expected them to work similarly to Word: if you click on a hyperlink that takes you to another part of the same file (another page in Word, another slide in PowerPoint).
In other words, I expected it to work like an action hyperlinked to the Last Slide Viewed (see Eric's answer here: Add a back hyperlink in powerpoint). But the Back and Forward commands remain grayed out.
Is this a remnant from other Microsoft products, which doesn't actually do anything in PowerPoint (in which case, I'll make a feature request here)? Or is this used for unknown-to-me purposes?
(I'm using MS 365, version 2404.)

Or is this used for unknown-to-me purposes?
These are used to change the layering order of elements on a slide:
Send object back one position. Ctrl+Shift+ [
Send object forward one position. Ctrl+Shift+]
Source: Use keyboard shortcuts to create PowerPoint presentations - Microsoft Support
Why would you use them?

Everything in PowerPoint exists on a layer, based on when the object was placed on your slide. Each object you place is added to the top and is therefore one layer higher than all of the other objects currently on your slide.
There are times when you want to change the layering order of the elements on your slide.

Source PowerPoint Shortcuts: How to Send Backward and Bring Forward

Further Reading

PowerPoint 2016: Aligning, Ordering, and Grouping Objects


Answer corrected.

After adding overlapping images, shapes, and word art on a single slide, selecting any one of them does not enable the "Back" and "Forward" buttons. So I don't think this is a correct answer. I commented this earlier - why was my comment deleted?

You have to use the shortcuts not the ribbon.

My question was solely about the ribbon buttons. Unrelated to these shortcuts, as useful as they are. Perhaps the word "Commands" was misleading, but I was trying to stick to Microsoft's terminology.
